# Rails - Ensuring an Event does not become over-subscribed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, model-view-controller

I'm building an Events app using Ruby on Rails. I need to create a system for bookings to ensure that an Event doesn't become over-booked. Each event has a finite number of spaces available - how do I ensure that if, for example, 100 spaces are available, 105 bookings are not taken.

These are my thoughts so far, along with some code I've tried but hasn't really worked.

**bookings_controller**

```
     def create
  @event = Event.find(params[:event_id)
  if @event.bookings.count >= @event.total_spaces
    flash[:warning] = "Sorry, this event is fully booked."
    redirect_to root_path
  else
    #code to save the booking
  end
end
```

In the views -

```
 <% if @event.bookings.count > @event.total_spaces %>

   # flash: "This event is fully booked"

  <% else %>

  # code to make the booking
```

I'm not sure this is sufficient to achieve my goal. Do I need a more robust method in my Booking model and some validations to cover this?

I've tried a transaction code block -

```
   Booking.transaction do

        @event.reload
        if @event.bookings.count > @event.number_of_spaces
        flash[:warning] = "Sorry, this event is fully booked."
        raise ActiveRecord::Rollback, "event is fully booked"
        end 
    end
```

but that didn't work as it still allowed a user to process a payment BEFORE the flash message showed up & AFTER the transaction had been completed.

I've never built anything like this before so am a little stumped. Any guidance, appreciated.

UPDATE -

**Booking.rb**

```
 def set_booking
return {result: false, flash: :warning, msg: 'Sorry, this event is fully booked'} if event.bookings.count >= event.total_spaces
    if self.event.is_free?
      self.total_amount = 0
      save!
    else
      self.total_amount = event.price_pennies * self.quantity
      begin
        charge = Stripe::Charge.create(
          amount: total_amount,
          currency: "gbp",
          source: stripe_token, 
          description: "Booking created for amount #{total_amount}")
        self.stripe_charge_id = charge.id
        save!
      rescue Stripe::CardError => e
        # if this fails stripe_charge_id will be null, but in case of update we just set it to nil again
        self.stripe_charge_id = nil
        # we check in validatition if nil

      end

    end
  {result: true, flash: :success, msg: 'Booking successful!'}
```

end

**bookings_conroller.rb**

```
 def create

    # actually process the booking
    @event = Event.find(params[:event_id])
    # as above, the association between events and bookings means -
    @booking = @event.bookings.new(booking_params)
    @booking.user = current_user
    handler = BookingHandler.new(@event)
    booking = handler.set_booking(booking_params)
    flash[booking[:flash]] = booking[:msg]
    redirect_to root_path

   # rest of controller code for booking
```

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. It would be good if you narrow down to one specific problem and describe your intent more clearly so that people can help you easily.

Comment: Okay. I will amend, accordingly. I am trying to ensure that an event does not take bookings over & above the number of spaces it has available. Are you able to help with this?

Comment: Whatever method you use, you'll need a way of locking/serialising the activity of adding a person to an event to avoid a race condition

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it's better to move validation to the model:

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
 validate :validate_availability

 private 

 def validate_availability
   errors.add(:base, 'event is fully booked') if bookings.count >= total_spaces
 end
end
```

Also I advise to read about Service Object pattern and use it in controller.

https://blog.engineyard.com/2014/keeping-your-rails-controllers-dry-with-services

Comment: Would this go in my Event model or Booking model? Also, should I keep the if/else statement?

Comment: @Mike.Whitehead Since you are manipulating of the Event model it should go to Event.

Comment: In your update you put too many things in a single method. Try this:
- use exceptions in your handler: `raise ApplicationError, 'Sorry, this event is fully booked'` and catch them in controller: `rescue ApplicationError => e; flash[:error] = e.message`
- extract things related to Stripe to a separate service: `BillingService.new(...).charge(total_amount)`
- use rubocop. it's gonna help you with code style - https://github.com/bbatsov/rubocop

Answer (score 0):

My first thought here is, remove the booking logic from the controller. The controller should only be concerned with responding to requests with data handed to it- so the bookings.count >= events.total_spaces should be moved into some sort of handler class- like BookingsHandler?

psuedo code--

This handler could take an an event as a single argument,

```
handler = BookingHandler.new(@event)
```

With a method inside that does the logic for you:

```
def book_event(booking_details)
 return {result: false, flash: :warning, msg: 'Sorry, this event is fully booked'} if event.bookings.count >= event.total_spaces
 . . . # booking code
 {result: true, flash: :success, msg: 'Booking successful!'}
end
```

With a simpler controller

```
handler = BookingHandler.new(@event)
booking = handler.book_event(params[:booking_details])
flash[booking[:flash]] = booking[:msg]
redirect_to root_path
```

As for the transaction block- this wouldn't really have any bearing on your situation as it's used to enforce referential integrity during related atmoic actions. So for example, only changing record A if record B is also successfully altered, rolling back any changes within the transaction if either fail.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. I'm trying to implement this code but I'm hitting the following error - uninitialized constant BookingsController::BookingHandler - with regards to the handler = BookingHandler.new(@event) line in my booking controller.

Comment: Judging by your namespace, you've probably just got the files in the wrong place. 

I tend to keep classes in the models directory, so in models, you could create a folder called 'controller_services'. Then create a ruby class called 'booking_handler.rb' which would define the class ControllerServices::BookingHandler. 

You'd then instantiate the class as ControllerServices::BookingHandler.new(@booking) in your controller. 

You can put the class in whatever directory structure suites your app, so long as the namespace is correct- best to keep classes in models or lib though.

Comment: Ah, I think I'm miles out with this, then. I've updated my code above to show you where I put the code you suggested but you're saying this all has to go in a different model file as it's a separate class in itself?

Comment: Generally speaking yes, independent classes should be in their own Ruby file. So class Foo should be defined in foo.rb. Namesapces in a class reference the directory stucture, so class Foo::Bar would be defined in a Ruby file called bar.rb, that resides in the foo/ directory. As these are plane old ruby classes, I tend to put them in the model/ directory. 

So this would be:
models/foo.rb
models/foo/bar.rb

Hope this helps.